# Assigning variable to session nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, authentication, db2, passport.js

I have created an authentication system using db2 for database, and nodejs for backend code. Yes, I know I could have used passport, but I wanted to try to build this auth system without it. I have everything working, and the way I am making sure users are logged into the system before it redirects to the desired page is checking if a global variable value is = true, and if it is, render the page. The problem is, the value of the variable is not unique to every session. I'm wondering if the best way to go about this is somehow setting the variable unique to every session, or maybe using db2 somehow. Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to handle such cases is to store a session cookie on the client side. Then, on the server side, build a cache map (mapping a session id to a data structure, that will include info about the session.

For this to be robust, support multiple instances of the service (for scale), and make sure sessions can be "forgotten" with TTL so the cache will not grow forever, it will be best to use a cache DB, such as Redis.

Here is an excellent tutorial on this: [How to Manage Session using Node.js and Express](https://codeforgeek.com/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/)

Answer (score 0):

Db2 session global variable values are unique to a connection. See [`CREATE VARIABLE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050499.html)

Comment: But be careful,  the value of a per session global variable may not be what you expect if the app-server uses XA protocol, or if the app uses connection-pooling, or if the database has the connection-concentrator enabled, or if an HADR failover happens...     Some things are better handled at app-server layer perhaps.